# R: Create new column by finding all numbers that are more or less than another given number in the same column with a condition in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following `df`

```
df <- structure(list(position = c(44188968, 44188969, 44188970, 44188975, 
44188977, 44188978), code1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

>df
position    code1
44188968    1
44188969    0
44188970    1
44188975    0
44188977    0
44188978    1
```

I would like to add another column `code2` (`1` if true, `0` otherwise) when the following condition is true:

- for each `position`, check if the other `positions`are located +/- 3 away. If true, the other `position` must have `code1 = 1`.

I would then obtain something like below

```
position    code1  code2
44188968    1      1
44188969    0      1
44188970    1      1
44188975    0      0
44188977    0      1
44188978    1      0
```

Could you please instruct me on how to achieve such table ?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my data contains `NA` values

```
position    code1
44188968    1
44188969    0
44188970    1
44188975    0
44188977    0
44188978    1
NA          1
NA          0
44189323    NA
```

In case of `NA` values, `code2` is also `NA`

**EDIT2**: As requested by @jazzurro, I am giving all possible patterns for my data

```
df <- structure(list(position = c(44188968, 44188969, 44188970, 44188975, 
44188977, 44188979, 44188980, 44189323, 44189324, 44189328, 44189330, 
44189334), code1 = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

>df
position    code1
44188968    1
44188969    0
44188970    1
44188975    0
44188977    0
44188979    1
44188980    NA
44189323    NA
44189324    1
44189328    NA
44189330    NA
44189334    NA
```

The desired output is the following:

```
position    code1   code2   # explanations
44188968    1       1       # code2 is 1 because 44188970 falls in the window of +/- 3 and code1 of 44188970 is 1. code1 of 44188969 is 0 so it is not taking into account.
44188969    0       1       # code2 is 1 because 44188968 or 44188970 falls in the window of +/- 3 and code1 of 44188968 or 44188970 is 1.
44188970    1       1       # code2 is 1 because 44188968 falls in the window of +/- 3 and code1 of 44188968 is 1.
44188975    0       0       # code2 is 0 because 44188977 falls in the window of +/- 3 but code1 of 44188977 is 0.
44188977    0       1       # code2 is 1 because 44188978 falls in the window of +/- 3 and code1 of 44188978 is 1. code1 of 44188975 is 0 so it is not taking into account.
44188979    1       0       # code2 is 0 because 44188977 falls in the window of +/- 3 but code1 of 44188977 is 0. code1 of 44188980 is NA so it is not taking into account.
44188980    NA      1       # code2 is 1 because 44188977 falls in the window of +/- 3 and code1 of 44188977 is 0.
44189323    NA      1       # code2 is 1 because 44189324 falls in the window of +/- 3 and code1 of 44189324 is 1.
44189324    1       0       # code2 is 0 because 44189323 falls in the window of +/- 3 but code1 of 44189323 is NA.
44189328    NA      0       # code2 is 0 because 44189330 falls in the window of +/- 3 but code1 of 44189330 is NA.
44189330    NA      0       # code2 is 0 because nothing falls in the window of +/- 3.
44189334    NA      0       # code2 is 0 because nothing falls in the window of +/- 3.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You want to check whether a position in one row is +- 3 away from all the other positions?

Comment: @tmfmnk yes that's right, for example, `44188969` includes `44188968` and `44188970` because they fall within the window of +/- 3

Comment: @tmfmnk also, the `code1` should be equal to `1` of the other position if they are located within +/- 3. For example, `44188969` has both `44188968` and `44188970` but also have `code1 = 1`

Comment: Why `44188975` is 0? You mean that each number must have both the previous and the next in the +-3 range? If so, why the first (`44188968`) is 1 and the last (`44188978`) is 0?

Comment: @nicola sorry if I did not explain myself properly. If we take `44188975` as example, the only other position would be `44188977` because it falls within the window +/-3 (`44188977` < `44188975 + 3`). But `code1` of `44188977` is 0. It does not meet the requirements, thus `code2` is `0`

Comment: but 44188978 also follows within your +-3 window right? or is it a +-2 window?

Comment: @Koot6133 `44188978` yes, they all follow the +/-3 window, in that case, only `44188977` is included

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my attempt. Given the communication above, the range you are talking about is +/- 2 (3 is not inclusive). I created two numeric vectors, which are for identifying a range with plus/minus 2 with each position. Then, I ran a logical check. Check if there is any position number that stays in each range and code is equal to 1. Then, I unnested the list, `check` and created a new column called `dum_position`. I extracted rows that do not have an identical number in `position` and `dum_position`, and `check` is TRUE. By this time, numbers in `position` are the ones we want to find.

```
library(tidyverse)

mutate(df, check = map2(.x = position - 2,
                        .y = position + 2,
                        .f = function(x, y) {between(position, x, y) & code1 == 1})) %>% 
unnest(check) %>% 
group_by(position) %>% 
mutate(dum_position = df$position) %>% 
filter(position != dum_position & check == TRUE) %>% 
distinct(position) %>%
unlist -> mynums

# Add 1 to the rows that have one of the numbers in mynums
mutate(df, code2 = if_else(position %in% mynums, 1, 0))

#  position code1 code2
#1 44188968     1     1
#2 44188969     0     1
#3 44188970     1     1
#4 44188975     0     0
#5 44188977     0     1
#6 44188978     1     0
```

Comment: I won't be around here after this. If you need further help. Please wait. If anybody can support the OP, please do so.

Comment: thanks for the proposed answer. I am getting an error `Error: Column dum_position must be length xxxx (the group size) or one, not yyyy`. Since I was giving a small subset, I forgot to say that there are `NA` values

Comment: @Zen Can you rearrange your sample data, which reflects your data's nature? Otherwise, I cannot see what is going on.

Comment: @Zen I just realized that you edited your question. But I still want to ask a few questions. The NA case you add is for 44189323. You just have NA around the number. What if you have an actual number like 44189324 and code1 is 0? Can you take a good amount of time and carefully identify all possible patterns that are happening in your data? Taking assumptions on my side does not really help. It can be just wasting of time.

Comment: @jazzuro sorry for the late reply, I edited my post to include all possible patterns. I will be more careful about it next time !

Comment: @Zen Thanks for the update. Let me see what I can do for you.

Comment: @Zen I used the updated data and ran my code above. I can get the expected result.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and your time. This works nicely !

Comment: @Zen You are welcome. I hope you can keep making progress with this.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using cross joins.

First create a lookuptable where you check for where code1 == 1 (df2)

```
df1 = df %>% mutate(cross = 'cross')
df2 = df %>% filter(code1 == 1) %>% mutate(cross = 'cross')
```

Secondly, cross join the tables, apply the filter and aggregate the results.

```
df3 = df1 %>% full_join(df2, by = 'cross') %>% group_by(position.x) %>% mutate(x = if_else(
  position.x < position.y & position.x > position.y - 3
  |
    (position.x > position.y &
       position.x < position.y + 3)

  ,
  1,
  0
)) %>% slice(which.max(x)) %>% select(position = position.x,
                                      code1 = code1.x,
                                      code2 = x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the proposed answer. This works well. I just have to take care of `NA` values now. I forgot to remind that there are `NA` values in my OP since I was giving a subset of my data, sorry for that.

Comment: I have an issue with the proposed code. Originally, I had `1448` entries. By slicing, I end up with `770`. I think this may be of `NA` values ?